Shadowing Lemma and Numerical Integration
Shadowing lemma tells that any pseudo-trajectory (numerically integrated trajectory) from some initial condition $x_0$ is the exact trajectory of a different initial condition $x_1$.

Q: Is this statement valid irrespective of the accuracy of the numerical integration?

I am numerically solving for trajectories of a (non integrable, chaotic) Hamiltonian system, the energy of such pseudo-orbit is found to change by order 1e-13 when run for time scales of order 1e4. Are such figures still under the purview of the shadowing lemma?

No general results is known for molecular dynamics or similar systems I think. See https://adsabs.harvard.edu/pdf/1992MNRAS.259..505Q however

Rigorously speaking, that's not exactly what the lemma says: It says that there is a (exact) trajectory arbitrarily close to the numerical one, it doesn't guarantee they're identical.
Also, notice that, although there are generalizations, (e.g., this), shadowing is proved to hold for arbitrarily longer times only for hyperbolic systems — so this is something to be aware of when trying to apply it.
And, friendly reminder: When integrating Hamiltonian systems you got to be careful with the integrator you choose, see this question.
Lastly, FWIW, to answer your question, without knowing any further details, I'd say an error of order 1e-13 seems pretty good for double precision integration.
